# PHP remove <body><html>...</html></body> from echo output

Tags: php, html, echo, strip-tags

I have a php script that does a query in my database and returns a string ( like "2" ). I print it using

```
print strip_tags('2');
```

but in the output of my browser I get :

```
<body><html>2</html></body>
```

Is there any way to prevent the tags from beiing printed? Is it maybe that the browser auto adds them?

---

For all those answering about strip_tags (" 2 ");

THIS IS WRONG:

I want a siple version.php
with 
   echo '2';

and nothing else. It prints the tags too. I don't have the tags and then try to print.

---

More explanation to those who try to get easy rep

my code is:

```
$str = '2';
print strip_tags($str);
```

and it prints

```
<html><head></head><body>2</body></html>
```

Comment: The body should be in the html

Comment: Browsers like Google Chrome for example automatically add the basic HTML tags including html and the body tag

Comment: All the people answering the same. Trying to get easy rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. The browser creates these elements automatically, without it there would not be any *text flow*(means nothing of this could be made visible). 
You can just use this variable for any script, **it won't include the HTML tags**. This is only made by the browser to make it visible for you.

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping for :D

Comment: This IS POSSIBLE. See my answer : tell your browser you're are sending text and not html.

Comment: @OlivierH I tested it..It becomes Worse ...Prints even more tags.

Comment: @OlivierH It isn't possible :) As i said, it can't make any text visible without these tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

at the beginning of your script, in order to tell the browsers you're only gonna send plain text, not html. This will prevent your browser from automatically adding those html tags.

Then, check what you `print` (or `echo`). Here, the `body` tag should be in `html` tag.

Comment: It isn't possible. Test your code with the header and see the result. You can't show ANY text in the browser without these tags. Plain text will result in a `<pre>` text, which still needs the default HTML tags. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414325/is-headercontent-typetext-plain-necessary-at-all) when to use.