# Compatibility mode IE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, compatibility, ie8-compatibility-mode

I made a lot of research on this topic but none of the found solutions helped me.
So, let's start: I have a VB ASP.NET WEB Application.
The problem is the users can see the source code of the aspx files in the browser (IE) when the `Display intranet sites in Compatibility View` is `unchecked`.
I tried all of the methods, settings compatibility from `IIS`, `web.config` or even from the `meta` tags from `<head>`.

I discovered that also with the `checkbox` `unchecked` if I use `Enterprise Mode` the browser displays the page ok.
I tried then to find a solution to force the Enterprise Mode from code but I didn't find anything without changing registry keys. Changing registry keys can also be done to the above checkbox.

If I go in the `DOM Explorere` in IE and I try editing the source, anything I delete from there, the page is displayed ok.

How can I force the Enterprise Mode, or the Compatility View Mode from code? or is there another solution for me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you need to check the caching of the application if you say that if you modify something in DOM the page appears.

Comment: page.Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
        page.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
        page.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"

Comment: what is the diffrence between them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414325/is-headercontent-typetext-plain-necessary-at-all