# Generate text file with new line using PHP running in windows 2000 using mozilla version 10

Tags: php, windows, firefox, newline, notepad

I am using PHP to generate a text file that is used in a computer with windows 2000 OS and mozilla firefox browser(its old dont ask why please). The file is generate correctly and runes smoothly on windows 10 and latest version of fire fox.

My problem now is that the new line does not render in the old version(windows 2000 OS and firefox 10)

I have tried using the ff:

```
1. /n
2. /r/n
3. <br>
4. $string = "This\r\nis\n\ra\nstring\r"; echo nl2br($string);
5. PHP_EOL
```

All not generating the desired output. It is just appending the BR as text

[image]

CODE IS :

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); 
header("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=something");  
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data).""); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['name'].""); 
echo nl2br(base64_decode($data));
```

sample text is : `"Assembly Lot Summary Report " . "\r\n" . "\r\n" ;`

`FYI` : Notepad(only) is used to open the text file

Comment: Add minimal HTML strucure: `<html><head></head><body>your text here</body></html>`. Creating static file first can help. Maybe browser missdetect something.

Comment: @DanielSęk it works in newer OS and mozilla firefox version. The new lines are added as expected. My only assumption is because the version of mozilla and OS is old

Comment: Do you want to generate plain text file for Notepad (in this case using `nl2br` does not make sense) or HTML file to open in browser (in this case `<br>` will be correctly interpreted).

Comment: unfortunately requirement is to use notepad

Comment: Make sure that generated file has `\r\n` line ends. Older Notepads (for example in Windows XP) does not handle line ends with only `\n` properly. Use `text/plain` as @Jimmix has written, do not use `nl2br`. Look up with hex editor what line ends are generated. You can also manually convert line ends (depending on client machine) and send file as `application/octet-stream` (binary stream).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have new line the same way you have in text editor when you hit enter key then the header should be:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

instead of

```
Content-Type: text/html;
```

so the web browser exactly knows that you want to pass a text file.

You may double check if the new line is returned to the browser by just examining the page source - go to meun > edit > view source or hit CTR+U

I would also try to remove this line:

```
header("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=something");
```

and see if it helps.

for generating new line from php you can use:

```
echo "\n";
```

or

```
echo PHP_EOL;
```

it will give you new line that depends on **web server** operating system - so different for Linux, different for Windows.

these are incorrect in PHP: `/r` or `/n`. you need to use backslash and they only work if double quotes "\n" are used [more read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character).

more read on [text/plain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414325/is-headercontent-typetext-plain-necessary-at-all)

Comment: the reason i didnt use text is because when using <br> it will just output <br> im using `\n`. still no avail